# Next. js Api Route not working in linux server

Tags: api, next.js, serve

I'm building an API in NexJs, everything works fine running locally (npm run start or npm run dev), but when I try to upload the server file from .next folder to the server and access to that path `http://serverIP/pages/api/welcome` I'm getting **Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at server ip Port 80**

**welcome.js**

```
export default function Handler(req,res){
    if(req.method == 'GET'){
        res.status(200).json({message:"WELCOME"});
    }else{
        res.status(400).json({message:"error"});
    }
   
}
```

**next.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
  
}
```

**package.js**

```
{
  "name": "ianos-app-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^9.6.5",
    "next": "12.0.9",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.8.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.0.9"
  }
}
```

Comment: Your API route path should be `http://<domain>/api/welcome`, remove the `/pages`.